# How can I automatically strip elements from an HTML file?

Tags: html, converters

I need to transform an existing HTML file to a new HTML file. The former has some elements that are no longer needed. Is there a program/tool that does this? I'd like to input the class/ID names of the elements into the processor and let it generate the reduced version of the old HTML.

Note that this is not just for one file. There are many such files that need conversion.

Comment: This isn't a converter. You can't convert something to same thing it already is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use XSLT transformation. This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) could help you.  And you also can try this [download](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Web_Authoring/Scripting_Tools/SimpleExport.html), but you need to write the xslt.